# Update manager keeps asking for partial upgrade

Tags: update-manager, synaptic, partial-upgrade

I'm on Ubuntu 16.04 GNOME, and for a few weeks, whenever I'm running the `Software Updater,` I'm getting the `Not all updates can be installed` error:

[image: Partial upgrade]

After going for the `Partial Upgrade` option, pending software updates itself (if any), else I get the `The software on this computer is up to date` message. Whereas the `Continue` option gives following message:

[image: Broken software index]

Running these commands:

```
sudo apt install -f
sudo dpkg --configure -a
sudo apt dist-upgrade
```

Aren't showing any problem, yet this message pops up every time. I even tried the `Synaptic Package Manager` and tried to fix broken packages, but nothing happened. How to fix this problem?

[EDIT] Here's the output of `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade:`

```
Ign:1 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease    
Hit:2 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable Release
Hit:3 http://ppa.launchpad.net/numix/ppa/ubuntu xenial InRelease    
Get:4 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security InRelease 
Hit:6 http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu xenial InRelease [102 kB]    
Hit:7 http://ppa.launchpad.net/papirus/papirus/ubuntu xenial 
Hit:8 http://ppa.launchpad.net/snwh/pulp/ubuntu xenial InRelease InRelease 
Hit:9 http://ppa.launchpad.net/tista/adapta/ubuntu xenial InRelease    
Hit:10 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial InRelease
Get:11 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates InRelease [102 kB]
Get:12 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports InRelease [102 kB]
Fetched 306 kB in 32s (9,375 B/s)
Reading package lists... Done
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

[EDIT] List of repos:

```
Canonical Partners
http://ppa.launchpad.net/snwh/pulp/ubuntu
http://ppa.launchpad.net/papirus/papirus/ubuntu
http://ppa.launchpad.net/tista/adapta/ubuntu
http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/
http://ppa.launchpad.net/numix/ppa/ubuntu
```

Comment: Instead of `apt`, try `apt-get`, as in `sudo apt-get install -f` and `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade`

Comment: " I even tried the Synaptic Package Manager and tried to fix broken packages, but nothing happened. " Can you expand on what "nothing happened" means? Did Synaptic show broken packages?

Comment: @CharlesGreen I tried the `apt-get` just now, still getting the problem.     @OrganicMarble When I go to `Edit -> Fix Broken Packages` in `Synaptic`, the status bar shows `Successfully fixed dependency problems` message instantly.

Comment: When you use `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade`, can you append the output of this command to your question?

Comment: @CharlesGreen done. check the edited post.

Comment: Weird - I don't use the Synaptic manager myself, so I'm a little mystified.

Answer (score 0):

1. Try deactivating the *unsupported updates* in the Software & Updates window.
2. Go to the tap, where you can see a list of repos. Look carefully on all checked repositories. Deactivate the repos you don't know and they seems weird to you like unofficial graphic driver repos

Comment: Already done that, the problem persists.

Comment: Maybe you forgot something. Can you paste your list of repos please. Note: I had the same problem like you and I have fixed it (see my answer)

Comment: I hope we find a solution in order to provide help for users, who have the same problem

Comment: Added list of repos. Check the question.

Comment: Do you know what do you have done before the problem has occurred?

Comment: Something special like adding to repo list

Comment: Everything was working fine, then suddenly this started to happen. I didn't add or remove anything

Comment: Maybe the problem is the software updater itself, because _apt_ isn't showing any errors to you. What you could do to purge the software updater and then reinstalling. But I don't know, if it breaks something

Answer (score 0):

Software Updater initiated updates began causing those *Partial Upgrade* dialogs after I enabled the

**Developer Options > Pre-release updates** (artful-proposed) setting.

Those dialogs stopped after I unchecked **Developer Options > Pre-released updates**.